# Open browser with http POST

Tags: javascript, html

I need to open a browser page with an Http POST request. Alternatively I can open with a GET request, which is the default, but then I need to pass a huge amount of data that cannot be passed in the query string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the request coming from?  In web land, the browser would already be opened.  From what environment/context will you be invoking the browser?

Comment: What do you mean? You want to send a POST request from a browser page? Or do you want the POST request to open a browser page? You can always redirect to a new page after making a POST request.

Comment: or maybe you mean you want another browser "tab" or "window" top open. maybe a pop-up? your question is way too broad.

Comment: The browser is open an running a web app. From that web app I need to open a separate tab an load a different web portal with a POST request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic trick is using `target` attribute of `form` element. You can submit using javascript with below code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function openWindowWithPost(url, data) {
    var dataForm = document.createElement("form");
    dataForm.style.display = "none";
    dataForm.target = "TargetWindow";//Make sure the window name is same as this value
    dataForm.method = "POST";
    dataForm.action = url;
    for (var key in data) {
        var postData = document.createElement("input");
        postData.type = "hidden";
        postData.name = key;
        postData.value = data[key];
        dataForm.appendChild(postData);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(dataForm);
    var postWindow = window.open("", "TargetWindow", "status=0,title=0,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1");
    if (postWindow) {
        dataForm.submit();
    } else {
        alert('You must allow popups for this map to work.');
    }
    //For testing invoking this function
    openWindowWithPost("http://google.com", {q: 'search', from: 'custom'})
}
</script>
```

Same behavior can be achieved with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><meta charset="utf-8" /><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="TargetWindow" action="http://google.com" onsubmit="openTargetWindowAndSubmit()">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function openTargetWindowAndSubmit() {
    //We are just making sure the target window is available before submiting the form
    window.open("", "TargetWindow", "status=0,title=0,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1");
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: Using simply `target='_blank'` or `target='TargetWindow'` opens generally a new tab. This is fine when new tab is OK with you. But when you want to submit in POP UP window, than giving the `window` `width` and `height` is required.

Answer (score 0):

So your only option would be to create a form, set the target to _blank, and trigger the submission.

```
<form action="/action" method="post" target="_blank" id="frm">
   <input type="hidden" name="foo" value="your huge string">
</form>
```

You can create it with JavaScript and submit it.

```
document.getElementById("frm").submit()
```